# Implementing custom namespace for non-opengraph supported og:type objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, namespaces, facebook-opengraph

I've successfully added a Facebook like button to my page, using opengraph tags to define it as an object in the graph so it is liked as an object, rather than a link.

I am using an ogtype=product meta tag, but the Facebook parser generates an error (see below) which seems to be elated to the fact Facebook no longer support the "product" type.

When liking the object, it is shown as a "Product / Service". This seems good, but with the parser error, and a need to understand a bit more, I'd like to resolve it and take the advice given to implement my own custom type which I may full use later.

My pages are review pages for existing product (single object product, multiple reviews on the same page), so I need to define a custom namespace to be able to do this. However, I am not sure I am doing it right...

I'm a little confused in general because it seems I have to have an app in order to do this and define a custom object and action (even though I have no immediate plans to utilise an action).

So I have setup a namespace (mySiteName) in my "App" in Facebook and I have defined an object "ski" and action "review" (for later).

Then comes my custom name space declaration:

http://ogp.me/ns#mySiteName: 
                  http://ogp.me/ns/apps/mySiteName#">

This initially passed the debug test, but then I noticed I had an extraneous  tag which I removed and I got a load of new errors:

Initial debug error:

> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input
>   metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an
>   unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only
>   expecting a single value, or property values for a given property
>   being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that
>   were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:type => product'

Code (no errors):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="{lang}" lang="{lang}" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#mysitename: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/mysitename#">
<meta property="og:type" content="mysitename:ski" />
```

New debug error removing extra  where only the mysitename namespace seems to be used:

> Extraneous Property:  Objects of this type do not allow properties
>   named 'og:mysitename:type'. Extraneous Property:  Objects of this type
>   do not allow properties named 'og:mysitename:title'.
>
> etc
>
> Meta Tag:  Meta Tag:
>
> etc

Thanks for any input - I've been trying things for hours with no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser works against the current Open Graph APIs, but 'og:type = product' is from the earlier version of the markup which was launched with the Like button in 2010 - documentation currently here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

It should still work, but [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) won't pass it, as it's looking for tags associated with the Custom actions and objects markup used with the current version of the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

For custom objects, the title, etc should be added with `og:title`, not `og:namespace:title` tags, maybe that's the issue with your 'ski' object?
In the Open Graph settings for your app, the object definition has a 'get code' button beside it which includes sample tags for that object:[image]
 - see how that compares to what you're doing

Comment: Thanks @Igy. I'd got that impression from various places. When the docs catch up with the newer API and the debugger and because - any idea why my custom namespace with custom object "ski" is not working?

Comment: Thanks again @Igy - Initially I had 'og:title' but for some reason my duff namespace declaration was meaning they were read in the debugger as 'og:namespace:title' even though my namespace was only in the og:type meta. I used the sample code via your pointer and it works. I was missing a space - not sure if that was terminal.